# Delete and Insert Into

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to execute a stored procedure everyday where it will firstly delete the data within a specified table and then insert the new data in.

My stored procedure looks roughly like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SP_Name]

 AS BEGIN

 WITH  CTE_Name as 

   (   select
        Title,
        First_Name,
        Surname

         From table

   ) 

   DELETE [dbo].[NEW_TABLE]
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[NEW_TABLE]

   Select * from CTE_NAME

    END
```

When I execute the query I get the error invalid object name 'CTE_NAME'

I have tried removing the 'DELETE [dbo].[NEW_TABLE]' line and upon doing this the stored procedure does run and does insert the data into the table.

I'm using SQl Management Studio 2012

Comment: What you posted is not valid SQL. Please post a valid code sample.

Comment: Move the `DELETE` statement above the CTE

Comment: Thanks Mazhar, gave this a go but it threw up more errors

Comment: A CTE is *part* of a query, not a stand-alone definition. In this case, it's part of the `DELETE` query. Even if you moved it above `SELECT` though it wouldn't serve any purpose. Why not just use `INSERT ... SELECT ..` with the fields you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to separate your With by adding a semicolon in front of it

below code should work

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (
 id VARCHAR(100)
)
DELETE FROM @TABLE
;WITH  CTE_Name AS
(   
    SELECT id FROM OtherTable
)    
INSERT INTO @TABLE 
SELECT id FROM CTE_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Name] AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @helperTbl TABLE (Title varchar(100), First_Name varchar(100), Surname varchar(100))
    INSERT INTO @helperTbl
    SELECT Title,
           First_Name,
           Surname
    FROM [table]

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[NEW_TABLE]
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[NEW_TABLE]
    SELECT * FROM @helperTbl
END
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, this is similar to what Mazhar mentioned above.  I have done this before and had no problems but that was by creating temp tables in my stored procedures.  I'm wondering if it's the CTE's it's not liking

Comment: @Clem_Fandango Try updated answer. It uses table variable instead of CTE.

Comment: @Clem_Fandango Sure, that DELETE doesn't like the CTE. There's a grudge between them.  ;) A `WITH` clause isn't stand-alone. It's used as a part of a SELECT. In a way, it's like a re-usable sub-query. So it would work with the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`. That's why it was recommended to move the DELETE above the WITH.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation LukStorms